# AuthenticationManager HttpContext is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I'm trying to use this code in my controller:

```
IAccountManagementService<User> _service;
public AccountController(IAccountManagementService<User> service)
{
    _service = service;
    _service.AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    _service.UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new DefaultContext()));
}
```

And it's been slightly adapted from the origin boilerplate code from the template for ASP.NET MVC 5

Its being injected via Ninject, Ninject is using a dependency resolver and module loader:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new ModuleLoader());

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

So I don't know if it is this messing up the context.

The service just has the original code abstracted out into it, the service looks like this:

```
IRepository _repository;
public AccountManagementService(IRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

public UserManager<User> UserManager { get; set; }
public IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager { get; set; }
public RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager { get; set; }
```

The original code looks something like this:

```
public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
{
}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}

public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

I could probably inject `IAuthenticationManager` but haven't really looked into it properly yet.

I'm just not sure when I load up my site, I click login and it takes me to the constructor of the controller and points to the line starting: `_service.AuthenticationManager` and tells me that the `HttpContext` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by re-doing all of my `Ninject` dependency injection. I'm now following the convention for `Ninject`ing MVC 5

I added these bindings for the ASP.NET Identity:

```
//<----- ACCOUNT STUFF ----->\\
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<EbpUser>>().To<UserStore<EbpUser>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", context => kernel.Get<DefaultContext>());
kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", context => kernel.Get<DefaultContext>());
```

To then get the `HttpContext` I binded the `AuthenticationManager`:

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InRequestScope();
```

Inside my `AccountManagementService` I just do this now:

```
IRepository _repository;
IAuthenticationManager _authManager;
UserManager<EbpUser> _userManager;
RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

public AccountManagementService(IRepository repository, IUserStore<EbpUser> userStore, IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore, IAuthenticationManager authManager)
{
    _repository = repository;
    _authManager = authManager;
    _userManager = new UserManager<EbpUser>(userStore);
    _roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
}
```

So now with everything injected properly it looks a lot neater.